# How to "npm install" programmatically using "npm" package

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Basically I want to install all dependencies in the package.json file. However, I want to control it programmatically using npm module

I searched for some results on the Internet but they just show how to install the specific dependency, not all dependencies in the package.json.

```
var npm = require("npm");
npm.load({
    loaded: false
}, function (err) {
  // catch errors
  npm.commands.install(["hello-world@0.0.1"], function (er, data) {
    // log the error or data
  });
  npm.on("log", function (message) {
    // log the progress of the installation
    console.log(message);
  });
});
```

P/S: Please don't suggest using exec, child-process or some sort like that. I'm in a situation that I can't use npm cli

Comment: Did you find a way to install _all_ dependencies programmatically ? I need it too.

Comment: As for 2022 this solution doesn't work anymore, npm >8.0.0 deprecated programmatic API, therefore `var npm = require("npm");` inside the project is no longer possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can require the package.json and parse its object `dependencies`. Something like:

```
const path = require('path');
const file = path.join(__dirname, 'package.json');
const pkg = require(file);

if (pkg.hasOwnProperty('dependencies')) {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(pkg.dependencies)) {
    const dependency = `${key}@${value}`;

    // Install dependency with npm module
    // ...
  }
}
```